# Umbraco 7 Multiple Textbox pulling "System.String[]"

Tags: razor, textbox, umbraco, umbraco7

I am currently using Umbraco 7.1.8 and I have just finished my final template however I wanted to create a tag like list for the client to add in as they wish.

I have a multiple textbox with the alias workUndertaken however when I call it, it echos `System.String[]`.

My code is pretty simple - I called it two different ways to ensure it wasn't an issue with one method.

```
<p>@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("workUndertaken")</p>
<p>@Umbraco.Field("workUndertaken")</p>
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry got the answer almost instantly. Was hard to find.

So I will post the answer with the code I am now using. Hopefully others find this useful.

```
@{
  if (Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string[]>("workUndertaken").Length > 0) {
   <ul>
       @foreach (var item in Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string[]>("workUndertaken")) {
          <li>@item</li>
       }
   </ul>
 }
```

}

Comment: This helps me out as well.  Thanks!